# C Timeout when calculate sum of every combination multiplication of three arrays

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

So I'm trying to multiply every combination from three array and sum them.

For example:

first array = [1, 4]

second array = [2, 5]

third array = [3, 6]

The total would be : `(1*2*3) + (1*2*6) + (1*5*3) + (1*5*6) + (4*2*3) + (4*2*6) + (4*5*3) + (4*5*6)`

And here is my approach

```
    for(i=0;i<in;i++){
        for(j=0;j<in;j++){
            for(k=0;k<in;k++){
                total += arr[0][i] * arr[1][j] * arr[2][k];
                total %= 100000;
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf("%ld", total);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine but somehow I get timeout in hackerrank and possibly because my algorithm is not fast enough

Do you have any suggestion on increasing the working time so I won't get timeout error in hackerrank.
thanks

Comment: Since you're asking for help on Hackerrank, which is supposed to evaluate your skills, I won't provide a solution. However, note the redundancy in your expansion of the total. It indicates that the current O(n^3) can be reduced to O(n^2). BTW, the purpose of total %= 100000 isn't clear to me.

Comment: I think a better aproach is to save the results of the multiplication of the previous arrays, and than multiply the next array with these results etc. And sum these options in the end.

Comment: `arr[0][i] * arr[1][j]` does not change inside the `k` loop. Maybe the compiler is smart enough to move that calculation out of the loop, maybe it isn't ... give it a little push :)